# How to concatenate variable in Makefile recipe

Tags: makefile

I get this `Makefile`:

```makefile
LIST = foo bar                                                                  
                                                                                
$(LIST):                                                                        
  echo $@
```

When I run make targets the outputs works as desired:

```bash
$ make foo
echo foo
foo

$ make bar
echo bar
bar
```

But if I concatenate a string `another-`, only `another-foo` works:

```makefile
LIST = foo bar

another-$(LIST):
  echo $@
```

```bash
$ make another-foo 
echo another-foo
another-foo

$ make another-bar
make: *** No rule to make target 'another-bar'.  Stop.
```

How can I concatenate a target to expand to all values in my variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you observe is standard: when writing

`another-$(LIST)`

make just replaces `$(LIST)` with its content, yielding `another-foo bar`.

That is, this has nothing to do with, e.g., a bash brace expression such as `another-{foo,bar}`.

Yet, you can achieve what you want by doing something like:

```bash
LIST = foo bar

$(addprefix another-,$(LIST)):
    echo "$@"
```